# MySQL AES_ENCRYPT() Length - Formula Explanation

Tags: mysql, encryption

To calculate how much data a person should project for cells containing MySQL [AES_ENCRYPT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt)-ed string, one should use the [following formula](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt):

```
16 * (trunc(string_length / 16) + 1)
```

The formula itself is not difficult. What I do not understand is the `trunc()` function. What does that function do, please?

Once I understand that one, it will be easy to calculate suitable length for `VARBINARY()` cells containing my encrypted data.

Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: It's an pseduo-code equivalent of `FLOOR` or `TRUNCATE`. e.g. strip the decimals off a division operation. `trunc(5 / 2)` -> `trunc(2.5)` -> `2`.

Comment: @MarcB, hi and thanks for your explanation. Understood and +1. If you wish, you can place your explanation as a regular answer. I will mark it as the accepted answer and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pseudo-code equivalent of `FLOOR` or `TRUNCATE`. e.g. strip the decimals off a division operation.

```
trunc(5 / 2) -> trunc(2.5) -> 2.
```

edit - dang... I just can *NOT* spell "pseudo" correctly today...